# Constant current in a coil determined by voltage in the same coil

Tags: current-source, magnetics

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYJibD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

My aim is to design a circuit that includes a coil with associated resistance and inductance. When an alternating EMF is induced in this coil by a magnetic field, I want to drive a constant current, determined by the EMF in the coil, in that same coil.
Is this possible, and if so, how?

My initial attempt was a simple Howland current pump however as far as I can see, any attempt to drive the coil will alter the voltage, thus altering the current in a feedback loop. Am I missing a solution here?

Note on schematic: the previous working version omitted OA5 and where R6 & R4 meet was connected to ground through a second coil. However, as stated above I am aiming to accomplish this with once coil.

Comment: Please draw a diagram with the circuit tool of your attempt.

Comment: Question edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Is this possible, and if so how?*

Yes, it's possible.

> *I am aiming to accomplish this with once coil*

No, that won't work as far as I can tell from your question. You need to have a second coil (see L3 below) that is used to monitor the open circuit induced voltage. You use that signal voltage to drive a voltage-to-current-converter and inject that current back into the first coil L2): -

[image]

I'm not sure if you understand the implications of the negative feedback employed here; because you are back-injecting a current, it will tend to cancel out the original induced EMF and this is an impassable situation i.e. it will always happen to a lesser or greater extent. For instance, if I increased the gain of the V-to-I block by (say) 10 you would get this a significant reduction of the original induced EMF: -

[image]

So, now the natural induced voltage on L3 is almost cancelled by the flux produced by the injected current into L2. Useful if you want to stop L3 picking anything up; in effect L1's flux and L2's flux are cancelling in the vicinity of L3.

> *Am I missing a solution here?*

I'm pointing this out because this may not be what you are expecting. Of course if you use positive feedback, things slam against the power rails hence, I'm sure you were not considering that. But, if this is what you anticipated as happening then, you are not missing a solution.

Pushing the coupling coefficient down to 0.005 and lifting the V-to-I gain to 1000 means you cannot "see" the original EMF with the scales used: -

[image]

And, here is the same graph but with a much more focussed look at the induced voltage associated with L3 (note the y-axis scale): -

[image]

Basically, what your circuit creates is a magnetic unity gain amplifier that works across a wide range of flux coupling. As I said earlier; useful if you want to cancel the presence of flux at L3 (there are applications).

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it would just resonate, and there isn't a good drive strength on the inductor because of R1 (it's limiting the impedance). You might want to try a transformer (where you have an inductor and a sense coil to sense the EMF), but I suspect that that would also be a problem because the current in the coil always has to be changing or the inductance will start to block it. You can't have a steady constant current through an inductor.

Comment: Looks like I might have to stick to two coils.

Comment: Also when you say steady constant current, does this apply as it is AC after all?